# Most Appropriate Authentication Type for MVC5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am about to start a new ASP.NET MVC5 project and I am planning the authentication / authorization requirements at present.

The client wants Windows authentication, to prevent their users having to remember another new password. The site is web facing, so the downside would be an ugly pop up box asking for their credentials when they are accessing it offsite. Worse yet, on mobile, this box would be a problem.

The Active Directory Authentication options from out of the box are new to me, but after some reading appear to be more about controlling roles and authorization through your AD groups. I intend to keep all authorization concerns internal to the application.

Ideally, users will have Window authentication but with a nice login page where they can select their domain from a dropdown box and enter their domain login credentials. From some reading I thought possibly ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider is the answer. However with the new available options I want to be sure there is not other options before blindly taking this route.

Comment: If you are going to downvote, at least say why so the question can be improved (assuming it's salvageable).

Comment: I didn't downvote but per my reading, your question reads like asking to recommend a tool / library, off-topic here: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: Maybe needs reworded then as that isn't the case. I will re-think wording. ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider could do what I need, but I am unsure if an OOTB options is a better fit

Comment: If it helps, i've created an MVC5 application with OWIN that uses windows authentication. https://github.com/vishnu4/AspNetMVC5WinAuth . Pretty easy to switch between active directory and forms if you need to.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I found [This](http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/) which is cleanest i've found. I have confirmed the new OOTB options are not suited. This is just showig switching out form membership to use the AD Membership instead. You can then just clear out all the ApplicationUser stuff.

Comment: Active Directory?  Yikes.  What if it's just a mom and pop store?  What does "not suited" mean?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The requirement I am needing to fill is Active Directory. I wanted to avoid just using windows authentication though as the gray pop up box if accessed remotely is ugly. the link gives an overview, I would be moving the auth stuff to an auth class and injecting it in to the controller. The "not suited" refers to the new ASP.NET authentication options added in VS2013